# How can I put each td value inside tr with $.each function in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a code in js to put each td value dynamically with in tr and code is as follows:

```
function salesList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.href + 'sales',
        method: "post",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#data-table").html('');
            let data_keys = [];
            let output = "";
            data_keys = Object.keys(response.data[0]);
            $("#data-table").append("<thead><tr></tr></thead>");
            $.each(data_keys, function (key, value) {
                value = value.replace(/_/g, " ");
                $("#data-table>thead>tr").append("<td>" + value.toUpperCase(value) + "</td>")
            });

            $("#data-table").append("<tbody></tbody>");

            response.data.map(function (values) {
                output += "<tr>" +
                    $.each(values, function (key, value) {
                        output += "<td>" + value + "</td>"
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                + "</tr>";
            })
            $("#data-table>tbody").html(output);
        }
    });
}
```

But the problem is tr has been added in browser inspector, but td with value hasn't been added within tr in the table as shown bellow.

[image]

But console.log(value) is printing for td in browser console as shown bellow. Note: Here I have made screen shot of a portion of browser console console.log(value) output.

[image]

What is wrong in my code? Can any body correct it, please? Thank you.

```js
const data = [{
  one: 'one'
}, {
  two: 'two'
}];
let output;

data.map(function(values) {
  output += "<tr>" +
    $.each(values, function(key, value) {
      output += "<td>" + value + "</td>"
      console.log(value);
    }); +
  "</tr>";
})

$("#data-table>tbody").html(output);
```

```html
<table id="data-table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building up a string, create a jQuery row element and append the cells to it. Then append the row to the table body.

```js
const data = [{
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two'
}, {
  three: 'three',
  four: 'four'
}];


data.map(function(values) {
  output = $("<tr>");

  $.each(values, function(key, value) {
    output.append($("<td>" + value + "</td>"));
  });

  $("#data-table>tbody").append(output);
});
```

```css
td {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table id="data-table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```